# Интеграция Яндекс карты в react-native е

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api, react-native, yandex-maps-jsapi

я хочу использовать яндекс карты в react-native аппликейшн,но нет sdk, сделал с помощью webview , но сейчас хочу использовать yandex maps suggestions чтобы получать имя мест,но не получается. Кто то столкнулся с таким проблемам ?

Answer (score 1):

А вы эти. библиотеки смотрели? Может они помогут.

https://github.com/volga-volga/react-native-yamap

https://github.com/escaton/react-native-yandex-map-kit

https://github.com/doomsower/react-native-yandexmapkit

Comment: Да смотрел, я использую expo, использовать эти библиотеки не получилось.